# How can i remove <p> </p> with python sub

Tags: python, html, string

I have an html file and I want to replace the empty paragraphs with a space.

```
mystring = "This <p></p><p>is a test</p><p></p><p></p>"
result = mystring.sub("<p></p>" , "&nbsp;")
```

This is not working.

Comment: ... keeping in mind that regex is bound to fail on someone's malformed html, like '<p>This<p>is a</p><p class="red"><P>test</P></ p>'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please, [don't try to parse HTML with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Use a proper parsing module, like `htmlparser` or `BeautifulSoup` to achieve this. "Suffer" a short learning curve now and benefit:

1. Your parsing code will be more robust, handling corner cases you may not have considered that will fail with a regex
2. For future HTML parsing/munging tasks, you will be empowered to do things faster, so eventually the time investment pays off as well.

You won't be sorry! Profit guaranteed!

Comment: it is already existing code in the company I got hired and they want to alter the regex...I have the suspicion some time soon it will fail. I ll try to move to a more robust solution.

Answer (score 5):

I think it's always nice to give an example of how to do this with a real parser, as well as just repeating the sound advice that [Eli Bendersky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406326/how-can-i-remove-p-p-with-python-sub/5406342#5406342) gives in his answer.

Here's an example of how to remove empty `<p>` elements using [lxml](http://lxml.de/).  lxml's `HTMLParser` deals with HTML very well.

```
from lxml import etree
from StringIO import StringIO

input = '''This <p> </p><p>is a test</p><p></p><p><b>Bye.</b></p>'''

parser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree = etree.parse(StringIO(input), parser)

for p in tree.xpath("//p"):
    if len(p):
        continue
    t = p.text
    if not (t and t.strip()):
        p.getparent().remove(p)

print etree.tostring(tree.getroot(), pretty_print=True)
```

... which produces the output:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p>This </p>
    <p>is a test</p>
    <p>
      <b>Bye.</b>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

*Note that I misread the question when replying to this, and I'm only removing the empty `<p>` elements, not replacing them with `&nbsp`.  With lxml, I'm not sure of a simple way to do this, so I've created another question to ask:*

- [How can one replace an element with text in lxml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418201/how-can-one-replace-an-element-with-text-in-lxml/)

Comment: ++ for a real example, but you're smearing `BeautifulSoup` for no reason. The page you links to explicitly says it's an old version and historic, and the module no longer has these problems

Comment: @Eli Bendersky: thanks for correcting that misunderstanding, I've removed that bit from my answer now.  I didn't realize that situation had changed, and hadn't re-read the page I linked to - mea culpa...

Comment: There is a bug in this snippet. If all the text content of p is wrapped in another element - `<p><b>This will be dropped</b></p>`, above code will remove that since `node.text` only contains the text that is present between the start tag and the start of the first child.

Answer (score 2):

I think for this particular problem a parsing module would be overkill

simply that function:

```
>>> mystring = "This <p></p><p>is a test</p><p></p><p></p>"

>>> mystring.replace("<p></p>","&nbsp;")
'This &nbsp;<p>is a test</p>&nbsp;&nbsp;'
```

Answer (score 2):

What if `<p>` is entered as `<P>`, or `< p >`, or has an attribute added, or is given using the empty tag syntax `<P/>`?  Pyparsing's HTML tag support handles all of these variations:

```
from pyparsing import makeHTMLTags, replaceWith, withAttribute

mystring = 'This <p></p><p>is a test</p><p align="left"></p><P> </p><P/>'

p,pEnd = makeHTMLTags("P")
emptyP = p.copy().setParseAction(withAttribute(empty=True))

null_paragraph = emptyP | p+pEnd
null_paragraph.setParseAction(replaceWith("&nbsp;"))

print null_paragraph.transformString(mystring)
```

Prints:

```
This &nbsp;<p>is a test</p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

Answer (score 1):

using regexp ?

```
import re
result = re.sub("<p>\s*</p>","&nbsp;", mystring, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

compile the regexp if you use it often.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote that code:

```
from lxml import etree
from StringIO import StringIO

html_tags = """<div><ul><li>PID temperature controller</li> <li>Smart and reliable</li> <li>Auto-diagnosing</li> <li>Auto setting</li> <li>Intelligent control</li> <li>2-Rows 4-Digits LED display</li> <li>Widely applied in the display and control of the parameter of temperature, pressure, flow, and liquid level</li> <li>     </li> <p> </p></ul> <div> </div></div>"""

document = etree.iterparse(StringIO(html_tags), html=True)

for a, e in document:
    if not (e.text and e.text.strip()) and len(e) == 0:
        e.getparent().remove(e)

print etree.tostring(document.root)
```

Comment: Why the down vote? It's a viable solution. It's noteworthy, though, that lxml return a valid HTML string. So the input string will get wrapped in <html> and <body> tags. Output of the given example string is therefore: "<html><body><p>This </p><p>is a test</p></body></html>"