# how to remove an element in lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I need to completely remove elements, based on the contents of an attribute, using python's lxml.  Example:

```py
import lxml.etree as et

xml="""
<groceries>
  <fruit state="rotten">apple</fruit>
  <fruit state="fresh">pear</fruit>
  <fruit state="fresh">starfruit</fruit>
  <fruit state="rotten">mango</fruit>
  <fruit state="fresh">peach</fruit>
</groceries>
"""

tree=et.fromstring(xml)

for bad in tree.xpath("//fruit[@state=\'rotten\']"):
  #remove this element from the tree

print et.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True)
```

I would like this to print:

```
<groceries>
  <fruit state="fresh">pear</fruit>
  <fruit state="fresh">starfruit</fruit>
  <fruit state="fresh">peach</fruit>
</groceries>
```

Is there a way to do this without storing a temporary variable and printing to it manually, as:

```py
newxml="<groceries>\n"
for elt in tree.xpath('//fruit[@state=\'fresh\']'):
  newxml+=et.tostring(elt)

newxml+="</groceries>"
```

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Use the [`remove`](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.remove) method of an xmlElement :

```py
tree=et.fromstring(xml)

for bad in tree.xpath("//fruit[@state=\'rotten\']"):
  bad.getparent().remove(bad)     # here I grab the parent of the element to call the remove directly on it

print et.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True)
```

If I had to compare with [the @Acorn version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7981897), mine will work even if the elements to remove are not directly under the root node of your xml.

Comment: Can you comment on the differences between this answer and the one provided by Acorn?

Comment: It's a shame the Element class doesn't have a 'pop' method.

Comment: it's a shame xpath can only be used to select elements. it is like SQL with only the select statements.

Comment: The `remove` function detaches an element from the tree and therefore removes the XML node (Element, PI or Comment), its content (the descendant items) and the `tail` text. Here, preserving the `tail` text is superfluous because it only contains whitespaces and a newline. But, in some situation you may need to keep it…

Comment: To preserve the `tail` text and to optionally keep the element content, you can consider using the [remove_node](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66670197/1513933) function defined bellow.

Answer (score 31):

You're looking for the `remove` function. Call the tree's remove method and pass it a subelement to remove.

```py
import lxml.etree as et

xml="""
<groceries>
  <fruit state="rotten">apple</fruit>
  <fruit state="fresh">pear</fruit>
  <punnet>
    <fruit state="rotten">strawberry</fruit>
    <fruit state="fresh">blueberry</fruit>
  </punnet>
  <fruit state="fresh">starfruit</fruit>
  <fruit state="rotten">mango</fruit>
  <fruit state="fresh">peach</fruit>
</groceries>
"""

tree=et.fromstring(xml)

for bad in tree.xpath("//fruit[@state='rotten']"):
    bad.getparent().remove(bad)

print et.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True)
```

**Result:**

```
<groceries>
  <fruit state="fresh">pear</fruit>
  <fruit state="fresh">starfruit</fruit>
  <fruit state="fresh">peach</fruit>
</groceries>
```

Comment: You've just got all the lxml-related answers for me, don't you? ;-)

Comment: Can you comment on the differences between this answer and the one provided by Cedric?

Comment: Ah, I overlooked the fact that `.remove()` requires the element to be a child of the element you are calling it on. So you need to call it on the parent of the element you want to remove. Answer corrected.

Comment: @Acorn :  that's it, if the element to remove were not directly under the root node, it would have fail.

Comment: understood.  Does it need to be a child or any descendant? I ask because, given the fact that the xpath expression is run on `tree`, is is certain that any element that is returned is a descendant of `tree`, and therefore `tree.remove()` would work properly.

Comment: @ewok: it needs to be a child. Try `tree.remove(bad)` with the updated xml above and you'll see the exception.

Comment: @ewok: give Cédric the accept as he answered **1 second** earlier than me, and more importantly, his answer was correct :)

Comment: If you can only remove a child of an element, how do you remove the root element?

Answer (score 15):

I met one situation:

```html
<div>
    <script>
        some code
    </script>
    text here
</div>
```

`div.remove(script)` will remove the `text here` part which I didn't mean to.

following the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418201/how-can-one-replace-an-element-with-text-in-lxml#answer-5420500), I found that `etree.strip_elements` is a better solution for me, which you can control whether or not you will remove the text behind with `with_tail=(bool)` param.

But still I don't know if this can use xpath filter for tag. Just put this for informing.

Here is the doc:

> strip_elements(tree_or_element, *tag_names, with_tail=True)
>
> Delete all elements with the provided tag names from a tree or
>   subtree.  This will remove the elements and their entire subtree,
>   including all their attributes, text content and descendants.  It
>   will also remove the tail text of the element unless you
>   explicitly set the `with_tail` keyword argument option to False.
>
> Tag names can contain wildcards as in `_Element.iter`.
>
> Note that this will not delete the element (or ElementTree root
>   element) that you passed even if it matches.  It will only treat
>   its descendants.  If you want to include the root element, check
>   its tag name directly before even calling this function.
>
> Example usage::
>
> ```
>    strip_elements(some_element,
>        'simpletagname',             # non-namespaced tag
>        '{http://some/ns}tagname',   # namespaced tag
>        '{http://some/other/ns}*'    # any tag from a namespace
>        lxml.etree.Comment           # comments
>        )
> ```

Comment: Notice that `strip_elements` (and `strip_tags` too) removes *all* descendant elements which tag name matches one of the * tag_names* names.

Answer (score 5):

As already mentioned, you can use the `remove()` method to delete (sub)elements from the tree:

```
for bad in tree.xpath("//fruit[@state=\'rotten\']"):
  bad.getparent().remove(bad)
```

But it removes the element including its `tail`, which is a problem if you are processing mixed-content documents like HTML:

```
<div><fruit state="rotten">avocado</fruit> Hello!</div>
```

Becomes

```
<div></div>
```

Which is I suppose what you not always want :)
I have created helper function to remove just the element and keep its tail:

```py
def remove_element(el):
    parent = el.getparent()
    if el.tail.strip():
        prev = el.getprevious()
        if prev:
            prev.tail = (prev.tail or '') + el.tail
        else:
            parent.text = (parent.text or '') + el.tail
    parent.remove(el)

for bad in tree.xpath("//fruit[@state=\'rotten\']"):
    remove_element(bad)
```

This way it will keep the tail text:

```
<div> Hello!</div>
```

Comment: Check the `el.tail is not None`, as there might be such a case.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use html from lxml to solve that:

```py
from lxml import html

xml="""
<groceries>
  <fruit state="rotten">apple</fruit>
  <fruit state="fresh">pear</fruit>
  <fruit state="fresh">starfruit</fruit>
  <fruit state="rotten">mango</fruit>
  <fruit state="fresh">peach</fruit>
</groceries>
"""

tree = html.fromstring(xml)

print("//BEFORE")
print(html.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True).decode("utf-8"))

for i in tree.xpath("//fruit[@state='rotten']"):
    i.drop_tree()

print("//AFTER")
print(html.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True).decode("utf-8"))
```

It should output this:

```html
//BEFORE
<groceries>
  <fruit state="rotten">apple</fruit>
  <fruit state="fresh">pear</fruit>
  <fruit state="fresh">starfruit</fruit>
  <fruit state="rotten">mango</fruit>
  <fruit state="fresh">peach</fruit>
</groceries>


//AFTER
<groceries>
  
  <fruit state="fresh">pear</fruit>
  <fruit state="fresh">starfruit</fruit>
  
  <fruit state="fresh">peach</fruit>
</groceries>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `remove` function detaches an element from the tree and therefore removes the XML node (Element, PI or Comment), its content (the descendant items) and the `tail` text. Here, preserving the `tail` text is superfluous because it only contains whitespaces and a newline, which can be considered ignorable whitespaces.

To remove a element (and its content), preserving its `tail`, you can use the following function:

```py
def remove_node(child, keep_content=False):
    """
    Remove an XML element, preserving its tail text.

    :param child: XML element to remove
    :param keep_content: ``True`` to keep child text and sub-elements.
    """
    parent = child.getparent()
    parent_text = parent.text or u""
    prev_node = child.getprevious()
    if keep_content:
        # insert: child text
        child_text = child.text or u""
        if prev_node is None:
            parent.text = u"{0}{1}".format(parent_text, child_text) or None
        else:
            prev_tail = prev_node.tail or u""
            prev_node.tail = u"{0}{1}".format(prev_tail, child_text) or None
        # insert: child elements
        index = parent.index(child)
        parent[index:index] = child[:]
    # insert: child tail
    parent_text = parent.text or u""
    prev_node = child.getprevious()
    child_tail = child.tail or u""
    if prev_node is None:
        parent.text = u"{0}{1}".format(parent_text, child_tail) or None
    else:
        prev_tail = prev_node.tail or u""
        prev_node.tail = u"{0}{1}".format(prev_tail, child_tail) or None
    # remove: child
    parent.remove(child)
```

Here is a demo:

```py
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.XML(u"<root>text <bad>before <bad>inner</bad> after</bad> tail</root>")
bad1 = tree.xpath("//bad[1]")[0]
remove_node(bad1)

etree.dump(tree)
# <root>text  tail</root>
```

If you want to preserve the content, you can do:

```py
tree = etree.XML(u"<root>text <bad>before <bad>inner</bad> after</bad> tail</root>")
bad1 = tree.xpath("//bad[1]")[0]
remove_node(bad1, keep_content=True)

etree.dump(tree)
# <root>text before <bad>inner</bad> after tail</root>
```