# How can I remove one tag from a html file in python?

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, python-3.x

How can I remove a `<ul>` tag from an html file with python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

most python xml/html parsers have methods to remove elements

2 ways are:

[how to remove an element in lxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7981840/how-to-remove-an-element-in-lxml)

http://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#extract