# XPath stripping HTML markup?

Tags: python, python-2.7, xpath

I am using the following with BeautifulSoup to fetch text from: https://alas.aws.amazon.com/ALAS-2015-530.html

```
description = " ".join(xpath_parse(tree, '//div[@id="issue_overview"]/p/text()')).replace('. ()', '.\n')
```

However, the content is stripped of all HTML tags. I get - "As discussed in  , Ruby's OpenSSL extension suffers a vulnerability through overly permissive matching of hostnames, which can lea
d to similar bugs such as  ."

My xpath_parse is simple:

```
    def xpath_parse(tree, xfilter):
  return tree.xpath(xfilter)
```

Can someone tell me why is this happening?

Comment: You're asking for a string created by concatenating text nodes. Text nodes aren't expected to have markup in them -- the markup is, well, all the **other** (non-text) element node types.

Comment: ...which is to say: Your XPath is giving you **exactly** what it's written to return.

Answer (score 2):

That's because of the `/text()` part - it would get all the text nodes directly located under the `/div[@id="issue_overview"]/p` only.

Instead, assuming you are using the `lxml.html` package, use [`.text_content()`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#html-element-methods) method:

> Returns the text content of the element, including the text content of its children, with no markup.

```
tree.xpath('//div[@id="issue_overview"]')[0].text_content()
```

Demo:

```
>>> from lxml.html import fromstring
>>> import requests
>>>
>>> url = "https://alas.aws.amazon.com/ALAS-2015-530.html"
>>> response = requests.get(url)
>>> root = fromstring(response.content)
>>> overview = root.xpath('//div[@id="issue_overview"]')[0].text_content().replace("Issue Overview:", "").strip()
>>> print(overview)                                                                                                                                                                                      
As discussed in an upstream announcement, Ruby's OpenSSL extension suffers a vulnerability through overly permissive matching of hostnames, which can lead to similar bugs such as CVE-2014-1492 .
```

Or, if you need to get the markup of the element - use the `tostring()` method:

```
>>> from lxml.html import fromstring, tostring
>>> tostring(root.xpath('//div[@id="issue_overview"]/p')[0])
'<p>As discussed in <a href="https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2015/04/13/ruby-openssl-hostname-matching-vulnerability/">an upstream announcement</a>, Ruby\'s OpenSSL extension suffers a vulnerability through overly permissive matching of hostnames, which can lead to similar bugs such as <a href="https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/CVE-2014-1492" target="_blank">CVE-2014-1492 <i class="icon-external-link"></i></a>.</p>\n            '
```

And, after removing the `i` elements:

```
>>> overview = root.xpath('//div[@id="issue_overview"]/p')[0]
>>> for i in overview.xpath(".//i"):
...     i.getparent().remove(i)
... 
>>> tostring(overview)
'<p>As discussed in <a href="https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2015/04/13/ruby-openssl-hostname-matching-vulnerability/">an upstream announcement</a>, Ruby\'s OpenSSL extension suffers a vulnerability through overly permissive matching of hostnames, which can lead to similar bugs such as <a href="https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/CVE-2014-1492" target="_blank">CVE-2014-1492 </a>.</p>\n            '
```

Comment: Exactly what @CharlesDuffy said. How do I get the markup? I got the text part alright. But it returns without all the markup.

Comment: @Metahuman ah, gotcha - I thought you were asking about the missing child node texts, like `an upstream announcement`. Okay, let me update the answer.

Comment: @Metahuman updated! Is this what you were asking about? Thanks.

Comment: It sure is! I adapted it like this - description = tostring(xpath_parse(tree, '//div[@id="issue_overview"]/p')[0])

Comment: Sorry I wasn't allowed to comment without unmarking as an answer. How do I get rid of the "<i class="icon-external-link"></i>" here?

Comment: @Metahuman sure, remove the `i` element(s) before issuing `tostring()`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7981840/how-to-remove-an-element-in-lxml. Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry, this does not work on large pages like these - https://alas.aws.amazon.com/ALAS-2015-522.html. It simply renders until the first < / P> tag.