# sed is deleting multiple lines when start and end pattern is mentioned

Tags: xml, linux, shell, unix, sed

I have a xml file emp.xml

```
<?xml>
<employee name="abc">ABC</employee>
<employee name="def">DEF</employee>
<!-- abc@gmail.com
this comment is added
to <employee name="gh">
</employee>
-->

?>
```

I want to delete some employee details from this file. Employee details to be deleted are mentioned in other file delemp.txt
abc
gh

```
while read line
do 
i=\"$line\"
echo $i
find . -name "emp.xml" -type f | xargs sed -i -e '/employee name='$i'/,/<\/employee>/d'

done < delemp.txt
```

I am reading delemp.txt and getting employee details to be deleted and searching for employee name= and employee end tag but this code is not working

Even if I try

```
sed -i '/employee name=\"abc\"/,/<\/employee>/d' emp.xml
```

It is deleting first 2 lines i.e name="abc" and "def"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why it's not possible to use regex to parse HTML/XML: a formal explanation in layman's terms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la)

Comment: You don't want to use `sed -z 's#</employee>#\r#g; s#<employee name='$i'>[^\r]*\r##g;s#/r#</employee>#g' emp.xml`. It might work for simple files, but will fail when small changes are made in the input (maybe after a month or two).

Answer (score 0):

### correcting xml to be valid

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <employee name="abc">ABC</employee>
  <employee name="def">DEF</employee>
  <!-- abc@gmail.com
this comment is added
to <employee name="gh">
</employee>
-->
</root>
```

### using [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) and a proper [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) expression to remove a XML node

```
xmlstarlet ed -L -d '/root/employee[@name="abc"]' file.xml
```

### result

```
<?xml version=xmlstarlet ed -L -d '/root/employee[@name="abc"]' file.xml"1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <employee name="def">DEF</employee>
  <!-- abc@gmail.com
this comment is added
to <employee name="gh">
</employee>
-->
</root>
```

### finally :

```
while read name; do
    xmlstarlet ed -L -d "/root/employee[@name='$name']" file.xml
done < names.txt
```

Comment: Thankyou. But can't we do it using sed?I cant use xmlstarlet because I need some shell script or perl script

Comment: NO sed is not a XML parser !

Answer (score 0):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) in command line :

```
while read name; do
    xml_grep2 -v "/root/emwantedployee[@name='$name']" file.xml > /tmp/new_file.xml &&
        mv /tmp/new_file.xml file.xml
done < names.txt
```

Using [App::Xml_grep2](http://metacpan.org/release/App-xml_grep2) (to be installed)

Comment: this is not working for me as xml package is missing.any python script to do it without much package installs

Comment: All languages require to use modules, python need `lxml`

Comment: Your tags doesn't contains python and I give you 2 proper ways as expected by you. Installing a perl module can be very simple, even as current user (space).

Comment: Can't we do it using xml.etree.ElementTree

Comment: Do it yourself with this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7981840/how-to-remove-an-element-in-lxml

Comment: Could you please answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55520773/how-to-assign-dynamic-value-in-find-in-xpath-python