# How to assign dynamic value in find in xpath python

Tags: python, shell, xpath

I have a xml file

```
<root>
<emps>
<employee title="abc">ABC</employee>
<employee title="gef">GEF</employee>
<!-- <employee title="abc">
ABC
</employee>
-->
</emps>
</root>
```

I want to delete some employee details from this file. Employee details to be deleted are mentioned in other file delemp.txt abc gh

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
class CommentedTreeBuilder(ET.XMLTreeBuilder):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CommentedTreeBuilder, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._parser.CommentHandler = self.comment

    def comment(self, data):
        self._target.start(ET.Comment, {})
        self._target.data(data)
        self._target.end(ET.Comment)


parser=CommentedTreeBuilder()
tree = ET.parse('emps.xml', parser)

#tree = ET.parse('emps.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for e in root.iter('employee'):
    print(e.attrib)

val = 'abc'
#mv1 = root.find("./employee[@title='abc']")
#root.remove(mv1)
#th='//employee[title()="'+val'"]'
#xpath='//employee[title()="'+val+'"]'
#mv2 = root.find(xpath)
#print mv2
#root.remove(mv2)
mmm = root.find("//employee[@title='{}']".format(val))
print mmm
root.remove(mmm)
#"//*[@text='{}']".format(email)
tree.write("emps.xml")

tree = ET.parse('emps.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for movie in root.iter('employee'):
    print(e.attrib)
```

I am trying to delete xml node. If I give static value as name='abc' in xpath it is working but if I try to give dynamic value it is not working.Please help me

Comment: Welcome to SO. What do you mean by not working? Are you getting any error message? Did you  print the value from another file  and checked if it's having any extra chars like spaces?

Comment: It's not deleting the node.there are no extra spaces.xpath is not finding out if I assign val='abc' and trying to find root.find("./employee[@title=val]")

Comment: Can anyone help me?

Comment: Check this `root.find(".//employee[@title='{}']".format(val))`. It's working for me. Just added `.`

Comment: Thank you . It worked.BUt how can we remove if the node is in comments