# Strip a single element in lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I need to remove an XML element while preserving its data. The lxml function `strip_tags` does remove the elements, but it works recursively and I want to strip a single element.

I tried using the [answer on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7981840/how-to-remove-an-element-in-lxml), but `remove` removes the whole element.

```
xml="""
<groceries>
  One <fruit state="rotten">apple</fruit> a day keeps the doctor away.
  This <fruit state="fresh">pear</fruit> is fresh.
</groceries>
"""

tree=ET.fromstring(xml)

for bad in tree.xpath("//fruit[@state='rotten']"):
    bad.getparent().remove(bad)

print (ET.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True))
```

I want to get

```
<groceries>
    One apple a day keeps the doctor away.
    This <fruit state="fresh">pear</fruit> is fresh.
</groceries>\n'
```

I get

```
<groceries>
    This <fruit state="fresh">pear</fruit> is fresh.
</groceries>\n'
```

I tried using `strip_tags`:

```
for bad in tree.xpath("//fruit[@state='rotten']"):
    ET.strip_tags(bad.getparent(), bad.tag)

<groceries>
    One apple a day keeps the doctor away.
    This pear is fresh.
</groceries>
```

But that strips everything, and I just want to strip the element with the `state='rotten'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe someone else has a better idea, but this is a possible workaround:

```
bad = tree.xpath(".//fruit[@state='rotten']")[0] #for simplicity, I didn't bother with a for loop in this case
txt = bad.text+bad.tail # collect the text content of bad; strangely enough it's not just 'apple'
bad.getparent().text += txt # add the collected text to the parent's existing text
tree.remove(bad) # this gets rid only of this specific 'bad'
print(etree.tostring(tree).decode())
```

Output:

```
<groceries>
  One apple a day keeps the doctor away.
  This <fruit state="fresh">pear</fruit> is fresh.
</groceries>
```