# How to select specific HTML hypertext markup on Python with html.xpath

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping

While scraping the content of a website, I encountered an issue with promotional prices which are crossed and replaced with another price (with `<del>` and `<ins>` html hypertext markups).

Here is the HTML source code of the bit I am trying to take:

```html
<span class="price"><del>
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
<bdi>49,00&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">MAD</span>
</bdi></span></del> 
<ins><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>35,00&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">MAD</span></bdi></span></ins></span>
```

I am trying to select only the part in `<ins>`.

I have so far used this code to extract the price, but it makes no distinction between the crossed and actual price.

```
sourceCode.xpath('//span[@class="price"]/descendant::node()/text()')
```

I cannot figure out how to only select the `<ins>` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about we actually follow what `<del>` means *conceptually* and [remove `del` elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7981840/771848) before extracting price values:

```
In [1]: from lxml import html

In [2]: data = """<span class="price"><del>
   ...: <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
   ...: <bdi>49,00&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">MAD</span>
   ...: </bdi></span></del> 
   ...: <ins><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>35,00&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">MAD</span></bdi></span></ins></span>"""

In [3]: root = html.fromstring(data)

In [4]: for del_element in root.xpath('//span[@class="price"]//del'): 
            del_element.getparent().remove(del_element)

In [5]: root.xpath('//span[@class="price"]/descendant::node()/text()')
Out[5]: ['35,00\xa0', 'MAD']
```

I'd argue this is likely better than trying to write XPath expressions to handle the cases where they have both old and new prices or just a single price.